# Confused about usage of IN and TO in sentences of this type

Tags: word-usage

1. I'm new **in** C programming
2. I'm new **to** C programming

Are both of these correct or one of them is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually use the preposition "to" in this context.  You can also use at, but the preposition in, though grammatical, isn't so common.